# Shrink Azure Linux images

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Deploying a standard Ubuntu instance on Azure seems to create the VHD as 30GB. Is there anyway to create one that doesn't require that much disk space? I didn't think a stock Ubuntu install would not require that much disk space?

Comment: Is there a reason you would want to shrink the VHD apart from the fact that Ubuntu install will not require that much disk space?

Comment: This is off-topic for StackOverflow, as it's not programming related. Maybe ask on SuperUser? But... just remember that with regular (non-premium) disks, storage is sparsely allocated. And with Premium storage (and managed disks), you pay for the entire disk regardless of amount used. So, not sure what benefit you're looking to get

Comment: It's mainly so that I can minimise the VHD size for faster transfers as I plan to share these images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway to create one that doesn't require that much disk
>   space?

In Azure, you create Linux VM will create a OS disk, the default size is 30GB, we **can't** shrink it.

As a workaround, we can create a ubuntu VM on your local Hyper-V, create it with a small disk, then **upload** it to Azure, then use this VHD to create new VM, in this way, the VM's OS disk will smaller than 30GB.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I'm trying to do now, following the guide on how to prepare the VM.

Comment: @vonec We can follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-upload-ubuntu) to prepare this VM VHD, then use PowerShell or Azcopy or new portal to upload this VHD. Please let me know if you need more help:)

Comment: Thanks @jason I got it working and my image ended up being 5GB which is a huge difference. However the funny thing is that when doing the AzCopy, it still took 3-5 mins to transfer from 1 storage account to another. Which is bizarre... We might end up just using the Azure standard image after all.